# MongoDB aggregation: how to find common elements from two arrays of two different collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here I have two collections: users and messages. 
'users' has an 'user_id' field and a 'phones' **array** field.
'messages' has a 'receiver_phones' **array** field.

`users` sample

```
{
  "user_id": "123",
  "user_name": JaneDoe,
  "phones": ["123456", "234532"]
}
```

`messages` sample

```
{
  "msg_id": "678",
  "sender_id": "090",
  "receiver_phones": ["123456", "000000", "010342"],
  "content": "Hello world",
  "timestamp": "2020-02-05"
}
```

My goal is to find all messages sent to the user whose id is 123. In the case above, the result should be msg_id 678, because its `received_phones` contains one of user_123's phone numbers.

I am trying to use $lookup to join two collections to find all messages whose 'receiver_phones' field contains any element in 'phones' of user 123. I am wondering if there is a way to find all common elements from arrays from two different collections. I am new to mongoDB and failed to write a appropriate query.

Here is my query

```
db.messages.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'users',
    let: {
      receiver_phones: 'receiver_phone'
    },
    pipeline: [{
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $and: [
            { $eq: ['$user_id', '123']},
            { '$$receiver_phones': { $elemMatch: { $in: '$phones'}}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }],
    as: 'results'
  }
}]);
```

Here is the error message:

```
uncaught exception: Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$$receiver_phones'",
    "code" : 168,
    "codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator"
} : aggregate failed :
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please share some sample document

Comment: what's the error log?

Comment: use `receiver_phones` instead of `$$receiver_phones`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like following, when you use the co-related queries, you need to pass the value inside `let` using `$` as I passed `$receiver_phones`. You used `$eq` and `$in`, so have to `unwind` to flat (destructing) to check the phones. Then use `$group` to regroup it

```
[
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      let: {
        receiver_phones: "$receiver_phones"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $unwind: "$phones"
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$user_id",
                    "123"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $in: [
                    "$phones",
                    "$$receiver_phones"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$user_id",
            user_name: {
              $first: "$user_name"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "results"
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zSieU9uH6Yb)